# What should be the "learning multiple" of the up-sampling layers in the Fully Convolutional Network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a Fully Convolutional Network (FCN) for a dense prediction.

Authors of the [paper](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf) mentioned that:

*"We initialize the 2× up-sampling to bi-linear interpolation, but **allow** the parameters to be learned."*

When I read their [training prototxt file](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/blob/master/voc-fcn16s/train.prototxt#L500), the learning multiple of those layers is *zero*.

Should I change this learning multiple to a **non-zero** value to let those layers to be learned?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote shelhamer

> ​In further experiments​ on PASCAL VOC we found that learning the interpolation parameters made little difference, and fixing these weights gives a slight speed-up since the interpolation filter gradient can be skipped.

So you can keep `lr_mult` this way or change to non-zero value if you want them to learn. You can also set `lr_policy` in solver.prototxt if you want.

For details see [this thread in caffe-users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/I7PC9OSKUWE)

Comment: Thank you lnman, as you see, there are lots of contradictions in deep learning society. ;)